# Status Code 400; Bad Request: Post request not working

Tags: .net, json, entity-framework, api, postman

I have created a method below in which I want a view model to be mapped to the identical model of data. After this the data needs to be mapped then to a more simplified Order details model which simply shows the basics of the order being added into the database.

```
[HttpPost("api/settings/neworder")]
        public IActionResult NewOrder([FromBody]JsonViewModel jsonModel)
        {
            try
            {
                Rootobject newRootobject = Mapper.Map<JsonViewModel, Rootobject>(jsonModel);

               _context.RootObject.Add(newRootobject);
               _context.SaveChanges();
                AddToQueue(newRootobject);

                var details = Mapper.Map<Rootobject, OrderDetails>(newRootobject);

                return new OkObjectResult(details);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Exception thrown while posting order: {ex}");

            }


            return BadRequest();



        }
```

What Json input would work using the below model as input reference.

```
public class JsonViewModel
    {
        public class Rootobject
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int Parent_id { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }
            public string Currency { get; set; }
            public string Version { get; set; }
            public bool Prices_include_tax { get; set; }
            public bool Date_created { get; set; }
            public bool Date_modified { get; set; }
            public string Discount_total { get; set; }
            public string Discount_tax { get; set; }
            public string Shipping_total { get; set; }
            public string Shipping_tax { get; set; }
            public string Cart_tax { get; set; }
            public string Total { get; set; }
            public string Total_tax { get; set; }
            public int Customer_id { get; set; }
            public string Order_key { get; set; }
            public Billing Billing { get; set; }
            public Shipping Shipping { get; set; }
            public string Payment_method { get; set; }
            public string Payment_method_title { get; set; }
            public string Transaction_id { get; set; }
            public string Customer_ip_address { get; set; }
            public string Customer_user_agent { get; set; }
            public string Created_via { get; set; }
            public string Customer_note { get; set; }
            public bool Date_completed { get; set; }
            public Date_Paid Date_paid { get; set; }
            public string Cart_hash { get; set; }
            public string Number { get; set; }
            public Meta_Data[] Meta_data { get; set; }
            public Line_Items[] Line_items { get; set; }
            public Tax_Lines[] Tax_lines { get; set; }
            public Shipping_Lines[] Shipping_lines { get; set; }
            public Fee_Lines[] Fee_lines { get; set; }
            public object[] Coupon_lines { get; set; }
        }

        public class Billing
        {
            public string First_name { get; set; }
            public string Last_name { get; set; }
            public string Company { get; set; }
            public string Address_1 { get; set; }
            public string Address_2 { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string State { get; set; }
            public string Postcode { get; set; }
            public string Country { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Phone { get; set; }
        }

        public class Shipping
        {
            public string First_name { get; set; }
            public string Last_name { get; set; }
            public string Company { get; set; }
            public string Address_1 { get; set; }
            public string Address_2 { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string State { get; set; }
            public string Postcode { get; set; }
            public string Country { get; set; }
        }

        public class Date_Paid
        {
            public string Date { get; set; }
            public int Timezone_type { get; set; }
            public string Timezone { get; set; }
        }

        public class Meta_Data
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Key { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }

        public class Line_Items
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Sku { get; set; }
            public string Price { get; set; }
            public string Regular_price { get; set; }
            public string Sale_price { get; set; }
            public int Quantity { get; set; }
            public int Product_id { get; set; }
            public int Variation_id { get; set; }
            public string Sub_total { get; set; }
            public string Sub_total_tax { get; set; }
            public string Total { get; set; }
            public string Total_tax { get; set; }
            public Fee_Taxes Fee_taxes { get; set; }
        }

        public class Fee_Taxes
        {
            public Total Total { get; set; }
            public Subtotal Subtotal { get; set; }
        }

        public class Total
        {
            public string _1 { get; set; }
        }

        public class Subtotal
        {
            public string _1 { get; set; }
        }

        public class Tax_Lines
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Rate_code { get; set; }
            public string Label { get; set; }
            public string Tax_total { get; set; }
            public string Shipping_tax_total { get; set; }
            public bool Is_compound { get; set; }
            public bool Compound { get; set; }
        }

        public class Shipping_Lines
        {
            public string Method { get; set; }
            public string Total { get; set; }
            public string Total_tax { get; set; }
            public Taxes Taxes { get; set; }
        }

        public class Taxes
        {
            public Total1 Total { get; set; }
        }

        public class Total1
        {
            public string _1 { get; set; }
        }

        public class Fee_Lines
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Tax_class { get; set; }
            public string Tax_status { get; set; }
            public string Total_fee { get; set; }
            public string Total_tax { get; set; }
            public Taxes1 Taxes { get; set; }
        }

        public class Taxes1
        {
            public Total2 Total { get; set; }
        }

        public class Total2
        {
            public string _1 { get; set; }
        }

        public class Coupon_lines
        {

            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Coupon_Code { get; set; }
            public string Discount { get; set; }
            public string Discount_Tax { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Here is the required Json input:

```
{
                "id": 111,
                "parent_id": 0,
                "status": "processing",
                "currency": "GBP",
                "version": "2.7.0",
                "prices_include_tax": false,
                "date_created": "February 14, 2017, 5:05 pm",
                "date_modified": "March 3, 2017, 11:35 am",
                "discount_total": "1.2",
                "discount_tax": "0.24",
                "shipping_total": "0",
                "shipping_tax": "0",
                "cart_tax": "2.1816",
                "total": "13.09",
                "total_tax": "2.1816",
                "customer_id": 1,
                "order_key": "wc_order_58a338d1350",
                "billing": {
                                "first_name": "Test",
                                "last_name": "User1",
                                "company": "",
                                "address_1": "32 My Street",
                                "address_2": "",
                                "city": "My Town",
                                "state": "",
                                "postcode": "MT34 2RT",
                                "country": "GB",
                                "email": "test_c1@example.com",
                                "phone": "0123245565"
                },
                "shipping": {
                                "first_name": "Test",
                                "last_name": "User1",
                                "company": "",
                                "address_1": "32 My Street",
                                "address_2": "",
                                "city": "My Town",
                                "state": "",
                                "postcode": "MT34 2RT",
                                "country": "GB"
                },
                "payment_method": "cheque",
                "payment_method_title": "Check payments",
                "transaction_id": "",
                "customer_ip_address": "::1",
                "customer_user_agent": "mozilla\/5.0 (windows nt 6.1; wow64) applewebkit\/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) chrome\/56.0.2924.87 safari\/537.36",
                "created_via": "checkout",
                "customer_note": "",
                "date_completed": false,
                "date_paid": "1487091921",
                "cart_hash": "d6f1d5f70fadcc1e5f41965025f319ab",
                "number": "111",
                "meta_data": [{
                                                "id": 1226,
                                                "key": "_download_permissions_granted",
                                                "value": "yes"
                                }
                ],
                "line_item": [
                                {
                                                "name": "Woo Album #1",
                                                "sku": "WA01",
                                                "price": "9",
                                                "regular_price": "9",
                                                "sale_price": "",
                                                "quantity": 1,
                                                "product_id": 83,
                                                "variation_id": 0,
                                                "sub_total": "9",
                                                "sub_total_tax": "1.8",
                                                "total": "8.1",
                                                "total_tax": "1.62",
                                                "fee_taxes": {
                                                                "total": {
                                                                                "1": "1.62"
                                                                },
                                                                "subtotal": {
                                                                                "1": "1.8"
                                                                }
                                                }
                                },
                                {
                                                "name": "Woo Single #1",
                                                "sku": "WS01",
                                                "price": "3",
                                                "regular_price": "3",
                                                "sale_price": "",
                                                "quantity": 1,
                                                "product_id": 93,
                                                "variation_id": 0,
                                                "sub_total": "3",
                                                "sub_total_tax": "0.6",
                                                "total": "2.7",
                                                "total_tax": "0.54",
                                                "fee_taxes": {
                                                                "total": {
                                                                                "1": "0.54"
                                                                },
                                                                "subtotal": {
                                                                                "1": "0.6"
                                                                }
                                                }
                                }
                ],
                "tax_lines": [
                                {
                                                "name": "VAT-1",
                                                "rate_code": "VAT-1",
                                                "label": "VAT-1",
                                                "tax_total": "2.1816",
                                                "shipping_tax_total": "0",
                                                "is_compound": true,
                                                "compound": true
                                }
                ],
                "shipping_lines": [ {
                                                "method": "Flat rate",
                                                "total": "0.00",
                                                "total_tax": "0",
                                                "taxes": {
                                                                "total": {
                                                                                "1": ""
                                                                }
                                                }
                                }
                ],
                "fee_lines": [
                                 {
                                                "name": "Surcharge",
                                                "tax_class": "",
                                                "tax_status": "taxable",
                                                "total_fee": "0.108",
                                                "total_tax": "0.0216",
                                                "taxes": {
                                                                "total": {
                                                                                "1": "0.0216"
                                                                }
                                                }
                                }
                ],
                "coupon_lines": [ 
                                 {
                                                "name": "all_10",
                                                "coupon_code": "all_10",
                                                "discount": "1.2",
                                                "discount_tax": "0.24"
                                }
                ]
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is the problem you are facing? Should we be guessing your json file?

Comment: I added the JSON input to the question and the error i seem be getting once debugging is: System.ArgumentNullException' in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll.

Comment: Your `JsonViewModel` is an empty class. You're confusing nested classes with properties.

Comment: Wow, didn't spot this nested class. Why do you need this JsonViewModel, shouldn't you deserialize to this Rootobject directly?

Comment: I will try that now, in terms of the JSON is that all okay for input in terms of Rootobject?

Comment: I didn't analyze it field-by-field, but it looks good I guess

Comment: Did it help? If yes, then let me know, I will post answer for the future readers.

Comment: Yeah it did thank you very much all sorted now.